# Have Windows 11 generate DumpStack.log.tmp on C: drive

Tags: system-file, windows-11-v23h2

On my C: drive, there is a file named DumpStack.log.tmp with a date of 12/12/2023. On my E: drive, there is another DumpStack.log.tmp with a date of 1/1/2024. It looks like Windows 11 now generates this dump file on E: drive instead of C:. What do I do to have Windows 11 generate the file on C: drive instead of E:?

Bing Chat suggested change the following registry key:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl]
"DumpFile"="C:\dumpstack.log.tmp"

My DumpFile value is "%SystemRoot%\MEMORY.DMP." I can't find this file "MEMORY.DMP" anywhere on C: or E:. Thus, I'm sure if this key value is what I need to change.

Note: C: drive has a free space of 327G.

Comment: Windows will sometimes use a drive with additional space when the system drive is a lower capacity. Can you provide some specifics?

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the comment. I didn't know that. The C: drive has a free space of 327G.